Content not scrolling
I am attempting to ensure that the content inside the left-content div scrolls when the content exceeds the parent height.
However, for some reason, the scrolling content is exceeding its parent's height.


.main-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content-container>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.content-left {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.scrolling-content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
<div class="main-container">
  <div>Navgation</div>
  <div>Notification Bar</div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-left">
      <div class="scrolling-content">Scrolling Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div>Footer</div>
</div>



I have created a fiddle to demo my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqpnacv7/

on the fiddle you shared left content is the right content, which code should we trust ? Make yours a snipper so we can play with it directly in so

Add .content-container { min-height: 0; } for shrinking:


body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
}

.content-container>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.content-left {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scrolling-content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
<div class="main-container">
  <div>Navgation</div>
  <div>Notification Bar</div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-left">
      <div class="scrolling-content">Scrolling Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div>Footer</div>
</div>




Your problem is that the content is overflowing the container, but the conainer doesn't have a fixed height. So the container is not overflowed: the container is overflowing the parent.
Looking at the following snippet, the main container is marked with overflow: hidden to prove that the yellow container gets cropped


  .main-container{
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: red;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.content-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.content-container > div{
    flex:1;
}
.content-left{
    overflow: scroll;
}
.scrolling-content{
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
      <div class="main-container">
          <div>Navgation</div>
          <div>Notification Bar</div>
          <div class="content-container">
            <div class="content-left">
              <div class="scrolling-content">Scrolling Content</div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-right">2</div>
          </div>
          <div>Footer</div>
    </div>



Here's the fix:


.main-container{
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: red;
  }

.content-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
}
.content-container > div{
    flex:1;
}
.content-left{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: fit-content;
}
.scrolling-content{
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
<div class="main-container">
          <div>Navgation</div>
          <div>Notification Bar</div>
          <div class="content-container">
            <div class="content-left">
              <div class="scrolling-content">Scrolling Content</div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-right">2</div>
          </div>
          <div>Footer</div>
    </div>




is there not a way of achieving this without giving a fixed height, ideally I would like the left content to fill the remaining space?

I edited the first snippet, but a fixed height could be as i did lazyly height: 100%

You need to define height for all parent containers and the left container itself, similar to my example below. Otherwise the contents of the parent containers will adapt to the height of their content, i.e. their child containers.
Apart from that, don't use overflow: scroll, but overflow: auto instead, otherwise you'll always  get both a vertical and  a horizontal scrollbar, even if it's not needed.


.main-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.content-container {
  height: calc(100% - 2.4em);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content-container>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.content-left {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scrolling-content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
<div class="main-container">
  <div>Navgation</div>
  <div>Notification Bar</div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-left">
      <div class="scrolling-content">Scrolling Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right">2</div>
  </div>
  <div>Footer</div>
</div>



